# Getting the next date for a specific day of the week

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Given a start date of  2014-07-08 (Tuesday) I would want to perform a check to find the closest day of the week.

For example, I need to be able to perform the following calls:

- First Monday (should return 2014-07-14)
- First Wednesday (should return 2014-07-09)
- First Saturday (should return 2014-07-12)
- Etc.

I know moment.js lets you do something like

```
moment("2014-07-08").day(1)
```

To get the date of Monday this week, however I need to know if the DOW is before/after the current date and apply the offset accordingly; if that makes any sense..

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the first day of the week, Monday or Sunday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `7` if the day of the week you are looking for is or was before the current day of the week:

```
var date = moment("2014-07-08");
var dow = date.day();
var nextX = date.day(X + dow <= X ? 7 : 0);
```